# How can I correct my compass spritesheet path?

Tags: ruby, wordpress, sass, compass-sass

I'm going crazy trying to figure this out. I'm using compass on a Wordpress project, and I have the compass configure.rb file saved in my Wordpress theme root. Here is my configure.rb file:

```
add_import_path "bower_components/foundation/scss"


http_path = ""
http_images_dir = "images"

css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
relative_assets = true

output_style = :expanded
environment = :development

line_comments = false
color_output = false
```

The directory structure is as follows:

```
theme_folder
|
|-css
|-images
|-js
|-scss
```

The configure.rb file is in the theme folder which is serving as the project root. When I compile the folowing scss with compass:

```
@import "compass/utilities/sprites";
@import "../images/*.png";
@include all-images-sprites;

@import "compass/utilities/sprites";

@import "../images/*.png";
@include all-images-sprites;

#site-title h1 a {

    @extend .images-logo;

    display: block;
    width: 250px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-top: 73px;
}
```

I get the following css:

```
.images-sprite, .images-logo, #site-title h1 a {
  background: url('../images/../images-s4b3b787fa3.png') no-repeat;
}
```

As you can see, the image url is really messed up. Any idea why this is happening? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First remark: since you are using the `relative_assets` the `http_path` and `http_images_dir` options are useless since ignored by Compass.

The `@import` directive loads files according the property `project_path` for Scss files and the property `images_path` for images.
To known the value of the property `images_path`, you can type the following command in a terminal:

```
compass config -p images_path
```

You can note that the `images_path` has for value `"project_path" + "/" + images_dir`. So, to import your spritesheet, you do not have to specify the location of the images directory.
But, basic, you can't import all the images of the `images_dir` in a spritesheet. You have to regroup the images of a spritesheet in a subdirectory located in the `images_dir` directory (ie `images/icons`).

Once this is done, simply import your spritesheet with the directive `@import "icons/*.png";`.

#### Alternative way

If you want to create a spritesheet with the content of the whole `images_dir` directory, you have to precise the `generated_images_dir` option to point a different location of the `images_dir` (to avoid infinite loop):

```
css_dir = "css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "images"
javascripts_dir = "js"
generated_images_dir = "."
relative_assets = true
```